# iruby notebook only runs python

Tags: python, ruby, ipython, iruby

I have a new laptop and have installed python 2.7.9 and ipython 3.0.0.  I then installed iruby.

Unfortunately, the iruby server runs fine with `$ iruby notebook` -- but the Jupyter notebook only runs python kernels.

I'm sure there's some subtle bug in the interaction of the newest Jupyter version of the notebook engine, but I haven't been able to sort it out. Does anyone know the incantation to make ths work?

**Update**

As @cel comments below, this may be simply that `pip ipython[all]` installs, by default the new iPython/Jupyter server and iRuby doesn't talk to it. I shall try installing an earlier iPython and see what happens.

Comment: `but the Jupyter notebook only runs python kernels` - Does that mean the `iruby` kernel shows up in jupyter, but does not work?

Comment: That may be the underlying issue. The thing is that iruby *runs* the jupyter server, but then you can't ruby with it.  Maybe I need to make a virtualenv with an earlier ipython...

Answer (score 2):

I found [this dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/nacyot/iruby/dockerfile/), and followed the commands, which installed an older version of ipython, and now iruby works also.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I observed that `iruby` tries to run python2-version of jupyter notebook (which is wrong in my case - by default I run python3-based version).

Solution was pretty simple - change default ipython to run python3-based jupyter (I assume that all jupyter binaries are in your `/usr/local/bin`):

```
# backup old ipython, is is not symlink!
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/ipython /usr/local/bin/ipython2
# provide ipython symlink pointing to ipython3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ipython3 /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

Comment: I haven't tried this in quite a while, I'll give it another try.